# Create new col4 in df1 with a value1, if the single column in df2 contains the value2 from a column in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 for example is

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef | ghijkl | mnopqr |
| abcdef1 | **ghijkl1** | mnopqr1 |

df2 is

| col1 |
| --- |
| **ghijkl1** |

essentially I want to add a col4 to df1 with the value "MM" if the value in df1col2 appears in df2col1

the final df1 would be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef | ghijkl | mnopqr |  |
| abcdef1 | **ghijkl1** | mnopqr1 | **MM** |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and then chain [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to convert `True` to 'MM', and `False` to a NaN value.

```
df1['col4'] = df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1']).map({True:'MM',False:np.nan})

print(df1)

      col1     col2     col3 col4
0   abcdef   ghijkl   mnopqr  NaN
1  abcdef1  ghijkl1  mnopqr1   MM
```

Comment: Building on this, is it possible to concatenate col1 and col3 into col4 when col2 is not equal to 0 and the df1col2 value does not appear in df2col1?