# How to delete rows from df1 where the column2 value doesn't appear in df2col1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1 for example is

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef | ghijkl | mnopqr |
| abcdef1 | **ghijkl1** | mnopqr1 |

df2 is

| col1 |
| --- |
| **ghijkl1** |

essentially I want to delete rows from df1 where the column2 value doesn't appear in df2col1

the final df1 would be:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcdef1 | **ghijkl1** | mnopqr1 |

Comment: Same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73720889/create-new-col4-in-df1-with-a-value1-if-the-single-column-in-df2-contains-the-v/73721000#73721000) basically. Use `Series.isin` to select from the df: `df1[df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])]`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 i wrote `df1=df1[df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])]` but this is returning an empty data frame? i can see the data frames include matching values

Comment: Could there be whitespace around some of your values that's causing it not to match?

Comment: Could you double check the contents of `df2['col1']`? I would imagine that they have changed due to some operation, because if this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73721000/18470692) apparently worked for you, then `df1[df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])]` should definitely also work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have whitespace at the start or end of tha values inside your DataFrame or column names, as the guys pointed out above. i will try to show how to do it in this answer.

```
# striping whitespace from col names for both DataFrames

df1.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace = True)
df2.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace = True)

# striping whitespace from values in both DataFrames

df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

# droping rows from df1 where the col2 value doesn't appear in df2 col1

mask = df1["col2"].isin(df2["col1"]) # returns a series of boolean mask(True or False, for the condition we are looking for)

new_df = df1[mask] # Returns what you are asking for :D
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: all of my values are 9 digit numbers with 0s (e.g. 000123456) for padding and it looks like pandas may have turned these into numbers when it loaded them and removed the 0s. I wonder if there's a way I could force pandas to load them as a string instead.

it looks like this is also causing a problem when I run the `x.str.strip` because it's throwing a non string error

Comment: worked after I put the initial load through converters={}

Comment: try this , `df1= read_csv('file_name.csv', converters={'col1': str, 'col2": str})` .. etc

Comment: Glad it worked (y), good luck buddy

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes = df1[!df1.col2.isin(df2.col2)].index
df1 = df1.drop(indexes)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.